# replace user defined variable at re.sub in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re

ip = input("Enter the value : ")
line = "<test></test>"
```

**I tried the following scenarios**

```
re.sub(r'(\<test\>)(\<\/test\>)', r'\1#{ip}\2', line)
re.sub(r'(\<test\>)(\<\/test\>)', r'\1-{ip}\2', line)
re.sub(r'(\<test\>)(\<\/test\>)', r'\1+ip+\2', line)
```

i want to replace the line like

```
**<test>user_input</test>**
```

*how to use user defined variable in re.sub*

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: i am reading XML file.

Comment: That does not matter. You try to create the new string "\1user_input\2". There are two ways to do that: String concatenation (r"\1" + ip + r"\2") or format strings.

Comment: tq bro its working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new string that is your replacement format for `re.sub`:

```
import re

ip = input('Enter the value: ')
line_to_replace = '<test></test>'
pattern = r'(<test>)(</test>)'

# any one of these could work, but the first will likely be more robust
replacement = r'\1{}\2'.format( ip )
replacement = '\\1{}\\2'.format( ip )
replacement = r'\1' + ip + r'\2';

newReplacedString = re.sub(pattern, replacement, line_to_replace)
```

Or all in place as your question provided:

```
newReplacedString = re.sub(r'(<test>)(</test>)', r'\1{}\2'.format( ip ), line_to_replace)
```